# How do I enable/disable VMware Tools at whim?

Tags: linux-mint, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I have Mint 19 running inside VMware Player. VMware Tools is already installed.

Is there a way to enable and disable the VMware Tools without uninstalling it or shutting down the machine?

Can I do this using a bash script?

I am assuming there is no way to do this within VMware Player itself (on the host machine).

[edit]

Neither command seems to work.

```
titlebar@titlebar-virtual-machine:~$ systemctl stop vmtoolsd
Failed to stop vmtoolsd.service: Unit vmtoolsd.service not loaded.

titlebar@titlebar-virtual-machine:~$ systemctl disable vmtoolsd
Failed to disable unit: Unit file vmtoolsd.service does not exist.
```

Comment: These smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). *Why* do you want to enable/disable VMware Tools on demand?

Comment: I use VMware tools to transfer files between the guest and the host. I only need to do this occasionally, however. So I want to disable them most of the time, since it could be a security issue. (I think.)

Comment: Okay, in that case, I think the question you really want to ask is how to dynamically enable/disable *HGFS*.  That said, doing that from within the guest probably would really solve much security-wise; if you're worried about the guest attacking the host, then a malicious process in the guest could just enable Tools/HGFS/etc. first.

Comment: Interesting. There's no way to disable the Tools from within VMware Player, either, other than disabling shared folders.

Comment: (Oops, I meant to say "doing that from within the guest probably would **not** really solve much security-wise...")

Answer (score -2):

There is probably a vmtools daemon or service running.  You should be able to enable or disable that service using systemd or service.  I haven't played around with Mint in a while.  So, not sure if which one it is using.  If it is systemd, then something like

```
systemctl stop vmtoolsd
```

and

```
systemctl disable vmtoolsd
```

should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about the reverse? How do I re-enable the tools?

Comment: Wasn't able to get them to work. See my updated question.